# Showing there always exists a sequence of numbers in an arbitrary list that sums to a certain value

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

Suppose that the integers 9, 10, $\dots$ , 20 are listed in some arbitrary order $(a_1, a_2, \dots)$. Prove that $\exists i, 0 \leq i \leq 10 $ and $a_i + a_{i+1} + a_{i+2} \geq 44$.

This is saying that no matter how you arrange the numbers, in the first 10, you can get three in a row that sum to 44 or more. I assume I would use a prove by contradiction to solve this, but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s_1$ be the sum of the first three numbers in the list, $s_2$ the sum of the next three, $s_3$ the sum of the next three, and $s_4$ the sum of the last three. Clearly

$$s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4=\sum_{k=9}^{20}k=174\,.$$

The average of these four numbers is $43.5$, so ... ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. What if, instead of counting $(a_1,a_2,a_3), (a_4,a_5,a_6), (a_7,a_8,a_9), (a_{10},a_{11},a_{12})$, one summed $(a_2,a_3,a_4)$ or $(a_5,a_6,a_7)$? Or does this not matter?

Comment: @p3ngu1n: It doesn’t matter: the assertion is simply that there is **some** set of three consecutive numbers that sum to at least $44$.

Comment: Gotcha. So, although the mean is 43.5, none of the $s_i$ can equal 43.5 because the elements are integers. Furthermore, the smallest any $s_i$ can be is 30, which means there has to be a $s_i$ much greater than the mean? $\implies$ if any of the $s_i < 43.5$, there has to be another $s_i$ greater than the mean?

Comment: @p3ngu1n: Right. If all four were less than the mean, their sum would be at most $4\cdot43=172$, and that’s impossible. More generally, given any collection of numbers with mean $m$, either all of the numbers are equal to $m$, or at least one is smaller than $m$ and at least one is bigger than $m$.